# Hide option based on selected previous form in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 select forms. The first one is select 'status' and the second one is select 'division'. The second form's option is based on the first selection. I have 3 option in the first select that will lead to each 3 option in the second select, saved as array.
Here is the code

HTML

```
<div class="row">
                   <label class="col-md-3" style="margin-top:30px; margin-left: 30px; color: #0b0b0b">Status</label>
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                       <select id="status" name="status" class="form-control">
                           <option value="">Pilih Status</option>
                           <option value="Karyawan Kontrak">Karyawan Kontrak</option>
                           <option value="Karyawan Magang">Karyawan Magang</option>
                           <option value="Karyawan Pertamina">Karyawan Pertamina</option>
                       </select>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row" id="row_bagian" style="display: none">
                   <label class="col-md-3" style="margin-top:30px; margin-left: 30px; color: #0b0b0b">Fungsi / Bagian</label>
                   <div class="col-md-6" id="select_bagian">
                    {{-- the second select-option here --}}
                   </div>
               </div>
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $('#status').on("change", function(){
           $("#row_bagian").show();
           var myDiv = document.getElementById("select_bagian");

           //create array of each status
           var magang = ["A", "B", "C"];
           var kontrak = ["D", "E", "F"];
           var pertamina = ["G", "H", "I"];

           //create select lis
           var selectList = document.createElement("select");
           selectList.setAttribute("id", "bagian");
           selectList.setAttribute("name", "bagian");
           selectList.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
           myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

           if ($(this).val() === "Karyawan Magang"){
               $("#option_kontrak").hide();
               $("#option_pertamina").hide();
               for (var i = 0 ; i < magang.length; i++){
                   var option = document.createElement("option");
                   option.setAttribute("value", magang[i]);
                   option.setAttribute("id", "option_magang");
                   option.text = magang[i];
                   selectList.appendChild(option);
               }
           }
           else if ($(this).val() === "Karyawan Kontrak") {
               $("#option_magang").hide();
               $("#option_pertamina").hide();
               for (var k = 0; k < kontrak.length; k++) {
                   var option = document.createElement("option");
                   option.setAttribute("value", kontrak[k]);
                   option.setAttribute("id", "option_kontrak");
                   option.text = kontrak[k];
                   selectList.appendChild(option);

               }
           }
           else if($(this).val() === "Karyawan Pertamina") {
               $("#option_magang").hide();
               $("#option_kontrak").hide();
               for (var j = 0; j < pertamina.length; j++) {
                   var option = document.createElement("option");
                   option.setAttribute("value", pertamina[j]);
                   option.setAttribute("id", "option_pertamina");
                   option.text = pertamina[j];
                   selectList.appendChild(option);
                   $("#option_kontrak").hide();
                   $("#option_magang").hide();
               }
           }
        });
```

The problem is, I selected "Karyawan Kontrak" at the first form, then the second form that contain kontrak array will showed. At the same page, I change "Karyawan Kontrak" to "Karyawan Magang". The second form which contain magang array showed but the previous 2nd forms of kontrak array still show even i did already hide it by id in javascript but it didn't worked.

Please help me how to hide it

Link JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/npa6o9km/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my solution,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.setAttribute("id", "bagian");
    selectList.setAttribute("name", "bagian");
    selectList.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("select_bagian");
    myDiv.appendChild(selectList);
  $('#status').on("change", function() {
    $("#row_bagian").show();
    

    //create array of each status
    var magang = ["A", "B", "C"];
    var kontrak = ["D", "E", "F"];
    var pertamina = ["G", "H", "I"];

 
    

    if ($(this).val() === "Karyawan Magang") {
  
      for (var i = 0; i < magang.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", magang[i]);
        option.setAttribute("id", "option_magang");
        option.text = magang[i];
       $("#bagian option[id='option_kontrak']").remove();
        $("#bagian option[id='option_pertamina']").remove();
       
        selectList.appendChild(option);
        
      }
    } else if ($(this).val() === "Karyawan Kontrak") {
  
      for (var k = 0; k < kontrak.length; k++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", kontrak[k]);
        option.setAttribute("id", "option_kontrak");
        option.text = kontrak[k];
        $("#bagian option[id='option_magang']").remove();
        $("#bagian option[id='option_pertamina']").remove();
      
        
        selectList.appendChild(option);
     

      }
    } else if ($(this).val() === "Karyawan Pertamina") {
     
      for (var j = 0; j < pertamina.length; j++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", pertamina[j]);
        option.setAttribute("id", "option_pertamina");
        option.text = pertamina[j];
        $("#bagian option[id='option_kontrak']").remove();
        $("#bagian option[id='option_magang']").remove();
        
        
        selectList.appendChild(option);
        
      
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <label class="col-md-3" style="margin-top:30px; margin-left: 30px; color: #0b0b0b">Status</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select id="status" name="status" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Pilih Status</option>
      <option value="Karyawan Kontrak">Karyawan Kontrak</option>
      <option value="Karyawan Magang">Karyawan Magang</option>
      <option value="Karyawan Pertamina">Karyawan Pertamina</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="row_bagian" style="display: none">
  <label class="col-md-3" style="margin-top:30px; margin-left: 30px; color: #0b0b0b">Fungsi / Bagian</label>
  <div class="col-md-6" id="select_bagian">

  </div>
</div>
```

You are creating new option element in the onChange event every time. Instead of that create element one time only and update options in it onChange event.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to hide the items, just empty the drop-down box.

```
selectList.empty();
```

Hope [it](https://jsfiddle.net/h71e4kp2/) can help.